# Add foreach for toarray to a JsonResource in Laravel REST API

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, eloquent

I have a collection of genres for every movie and I wanna display every one that each movie has in the api request. Here's the resource:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'image_path' => url()->to('/images/' .$this->image_path),
            'genres' => ''
        ];
    }
```

I believe I need to access genres in Movie model and use foreach in toarray function but how exactly it should be done?
Here's my migrations:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('status')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->string('image_path')->default('default.png');
        });
    }

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('genre_movie', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('genre_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('movie_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }
```

Movie model:

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'status', 'image_path'];

    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class, 'genre_movie');
    }
}
```

Genre model:

```
class Genre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class, 'genre_movie');
    }
}
```

Function in controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        return MovieResource::collection(Movie::paginate());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a genre resouce.

```
class GenreResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Load it in the controller using `with()`.

```
public function index()
{
    $movies = Movie::with('genres')->paginate();

    return MovieResource::collection();
}
```

Add it to the `MovieResource`, use `whenLoaded()` and a closure, so you don't have to show it, if it is not loaded.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        ...
        'genres' => $this->whenLoaded('genres', function () {
            return GenreResource::collection($this->genres);
        }),
    ];
}
```

Comment: seems like it should work but I receive this error: ""message": "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.","

Comment: my bad used the wrong snippet, in the MovieResource it should be GenreResource::collection